# Как правильно спроектировать таблицы БД?

Tags: sql

Предположим есть сервис с товарами. Подразумевается наличие фльтра.

Подскажите, можно ли спроектировать базу таким образом: есть таблица "products", и таблица "tags".
Связь между таблицами - ManyToMany, соответственно есть промежуточная таблица products_tags.

В таблице tags имеются тэги, по типу "для нее", "для него", "для детей", "дорого", "популярно" и т.д. (теги вымышленные, но отражающие суть)

Есть ли смысл к каждому продукту цеплять теги и по тегам осуществлять поиск?
Или имеет смысл в таблице "products" создать доп. поля:
enum - "для кого",
bool - "популярно",
bool - "дешево"

Кто вник и понял суть вопроса, прошу Вашего оценочного мнения и аргументы в ту или иную пользу.

Comment: Если набор тегов статический, и их можно разбить на группы взаимоисключающих тегов, то можно полями в products. Если набор тегов динамический (с возможностью добавления/удаления кем-то, кто не разработчик) или есть предпосылки, что он таким когда-нибудь станет, то отдельная таблица и many-to-many отношение.

Comment: @aa_talanin, спасибо! Набор тегов действительно статический. Ваш ответ разложил все по полочкам в моей голове.

Comment: Если что-то реальное делаете, то лучше не рассчитывать, что набор тегов не будет меняться. Он  точно будет меняться. А вот такие основные категории, как производитель, вид товара, возрастное назначение, половое назначение и т. п., которые тоже присутствуют в фильтрах, должны быть в products полями.

Comment: @rotabor, пришел к тому же самому выводу! Спасибо!